# is it possible to change vertical to horizontal hours in Kendo UI Scheduler?

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

I want to change this:

[image: I am using resources to grouping my events]

by this:

[image: The hours are horizontal and the groups vertical]

Is that possible with Kendo UI Scheduler?

I am using AngularJS and JS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Timeline" views of the Scheduler to achieve the desired behavior:

- [Scheduler: Timeline views](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline)